# Rotation Not working in iOS-6.0 and above versions

Tags: ios6, uiwindow, autorotate

I have prepared one view controller file named "CncWindowController" and In XIB file, i take window object (instead of UIView) and connected it to view outlet. So when I access its view, i get  window object.

I'm accessing like it in AppDelegate.m file :

```
self.windowController = [[CncWindowController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CncWindowController" bundle:nil];
self.window = (UIWindow*) self.windowController.view;
```

Here, view is actually referring to window. But Rotation is not working in iOS6.0 and shouldAutorotate method is also not called.

If i will use window object like below then it works fine :
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

What is wrong with my approach ? Any help of ideas how i should work autorotation in iOS-6 too using above approach ?

Thanks!

Comment: check this http://dhilipsiva.blogspot.in/2012/07/ios-6-ui-interface-orientation.html

Comment: I have already added methods which is required for iOS-6. 1) shouldAutorotate 2) supportedInterfaceOrientations